# Are questions about variable names too localized on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes I find myself wondering what a good variable name would be for something I'm currently coding. Right now I spent 5 minutes (I know, I'm dumb) to figure out that a good name for a list of sort priorities would be "order_by".

Which got me thinking, is asking for specific variable names too small of a question for SO?

Comment: **Do not close!** The question is perfectly understandable. They want to know whether a certain question is acceptable for SO.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would say that it would immediately be closed as **primarily opinion-based**.

Here's the description for that close reason:

> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

I would say that there are no hard facts, references, or specific expertise about variable name length, etc*.

---

> #### *Although my opinion is they should be as long and descriptive as possible. Cue war in comments about variable names. Made big in response to George's begging.

Comment: I won't comment on the footnote, other than to say that the font size is not proportional to the value of the content. ;)

Comment: +1 for "opinion-based". *However*, it is worth noting that Java, then Sun, now Oracle, posted a very large document referencing many preferences for naming conventions, variable name lengths, and other tidbits. So I wouldn't say "there are no facts", as there are definitely a few. QED

Comment: @TravisJ Still, it could be argued that those are just *preferences*. Which are opinions, when it comes down to it.

Comment: @Undo - I would say that if it is published by the company who invented the java language, there are at the very least references and or specific expertise about naming conventions.

Comment: @TravisJ Hmm.. That's a good argument.

Comment: Still, I'm pretty sure that the 3k crowd wouldn't think twice about closing this.

Comment: @Undo - Oh definitely, I would agree that closing it is correct. There is already a question regarding the Java one, so even if that were to come up, it would still be a duplicate.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins You're just going to keep editing that until it's perfect, aren't you? :)

Comment: That, or until you make it at least 24-points. :)

Comment: There you go. Whee!

Comment: @GeorgeCummins *Now* we'll get some comment wars.

Comment: Almost; I say *as long and descriptive as* ***necessary***. `studentsArray` is great; `theArrayIntoWhichIPlaceEveryStudentWhoSignsUpForTheClassesWhichThisProgramIsConcernedWith` is a bit much ;) That would be a fun game on english.SE--making the names even longer, because who's to say when it's as long as is *possible*? ;)  Haha. But no, I'm just having fun. I agree with you in principle! +1

Answer (score 6):

It's tantamount to a debate on where the curly braces belong in a particular programming language.  Opinion-driven questions are definitely off-topic for SO.

Comment: I wish SO would support some kind of downvoting into closing. "Best practice" and the like are totally arbitrary kiss-of-death phrases for questions. And if everyone provided an answer in neutral technical form like "in language x it can't start with a number," I'd hope the question stays open. One person's interpretation is a poor way to gauge what elicits debate and effectively dismissing the question is a poor way to moderate answers.

Comment: There only 1 correct way in javascript though...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JWt6z/

Comment: @nik.shornikov:  I would refrain from that (while I do agree in some sense), since you could easily get a group of people together and gang down-vote a question/answer.  Which is unfortunate.